# Make Connection between processor and remote process group Nipyapi

Tags: python-3.x, apache-nifi, nipyapi

Nipyapi version: last version
NiFi version: 1.9
NiFi-Registry version:
Python version: 3.7
Operating System: ubuntu
Description
I wanna connect processor with remote process group using the API, what I should do in target parametre in canvas.create_connection to make the connection between both of them.

Please help me to solve this problème!

What I Did
I want to connect those two stuff together :

````
rpg__id = "46e9c4df-016f-1000-6eb5-e52138e0a1e3"
rpg = canvas.get_remote_process_group(rpg_id=rpg__id,summary=False)
canvas.set_remote_process_group_transmission(rpg, enable=False, refresh=False)
canvas.create_connection(source=RouteOnAttribute_root,target=rpg ,relationships=['unmatched'])```
````

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately NiPyAPI doesn't yet provide a high level call for this connection type, it is in progress in my local branch but requires non-trivial changes to the test setup to handle the variations.
I hope to progress it when I return from winter holidays.
In the meantime you can examine the browser calls using DevTools and use the low level API commands to execute it.

Comment: Hello and happy new year.


thank you for your response, I understand and I begin trying to do it with low level API. 
thanks Chaffleson